# Integrate $\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to compute the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x$ using complex analysis. I'm working on a problem for a complex analysis class that asks me to do so, but I'm struggling with how to do it. I know that it can be done using elementary calculus using a change of variables and integration by parts, and there are several such questions on this forum, but as far as I saw, none of them used complex techniques (and why would you?).

One thing I tried was to make a contour $\Gamma$ that traced the polar rectangle $\{ (r, \theta) : 1/R \leq r \leq R , 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi / 2 \}$ and then take $R \to \infty$. If I'm not mistaken, I found that the integrals along the inner and outer arcs would vanish as $R \to \infty$, and that the integrals along the two linear sides would be proportionate, telling me that $(1 + \lambda) \int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x = \int_\Gamma f(z) \mathrm{d} z$ for some constant $\lambda$. But since $f$ is holomorphic on the interior of $\Gamma$, this should come out as $(1 + \lambda) \int_0^\infty e^{-\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d} x = 0$, which tells me that either I messed up my arithmetic, or this approach won't help.

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think using change of variables is much of a sin as long as you evaluate the Gaussian Integral by means of complex analysis. However I am not a mind reader and I don't know how the person who assigned you this problem would think of such a method.

Comment: I agree with @Mr.GandalfSauron Applying complex analysis seems like a torture

Comment: I think you should use a "keyhole contour" for this kind of functions, and take the determination of the principal argument of z being $0 \leq \text{arg} z < 2 \pi$, leaving the branch cut on the real axis ($x>0$, $y=0$).

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I agree, but the problem says to use contours

Comment: @Luciano Could you elaborate?